# How to count values in nested dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I have a nested dictionary with about 150 keys , each key contains number of feature, one feature called ["poi"] contains (true or false ) values
I need to count all true values on this feature ["poi"]of my 150 keys

I have tried

```
count = 0 
for i in range(len(enron_data)):
a = enron_data.values()
if a[i]['poi'] == True:
    count = count + 1 
print(count)
```

but I got an error
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict'

[features of an key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhubA.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @AliSaid please add a language tag,sample data and expected output to get better support.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the code below

```
count=0
for i in range (len(enron_data)):
    x=list(enron_data.keys())[i]
    if enron_data[x]["poi"]==True:
    count+=1
print(count)
```